In Next.js, not using sockets but getting GET /socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P37KhCz 404 in 5344ms
I'm working on a next.js project using nextjs 15.0.0-rc.0, next-auth 5.0.0-beta.19, and react 19.0.0-rc-f994737d14-20240522.
The latest time I went to start up my project, I did pnpm run dev, and I got
> @ dev /home/dan/Concord/concord
> next dev

  ▲ Next.js 15.0.0-rc.0
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000
  - Environments: .env

 ✓ Starting...
 ✓ Ready in 3.3s
 ○ Compiling /middleware ...
 ✓ Compiled /middleware in 721ms (227 modules)
 ○ Compiling /_not-found ...
 ✓ Compiled /_not-found in 4.9s (463 modules)
 GET /socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P37KhCz 404 in 5344ms
 ✓ Compiled in 479ms (240 modules)
 GET /socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P37KhCz 404 in 77ms
 GET /socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P37Kk8T 404 in 40ms
 GET /socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P37Kk8Z 404 in 35ms
 GET /socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=P37KlcE 404 in 29ms

followed by the same thing repeated every few seconds.
This wasn't happening before the last time I started up my project, and I have no idea what I could have changed in my project that would have caused this. I'm not using socket.io for anything. Here's my package.json file:
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.4",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.7",
    "@types/next-auth": "^3.15.0",
    "@types/pg": "^8.11.6",
    "@vercel/postgres": "^0.8.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.19",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "next": "15.0.0-rc.0",
    "next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.19",
    "pg": "^8.12.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.38",
    "react": "19.0.0-rc-f994737d14-20240522",
    "react-dom": "19.0.0-rc-f994737d14-20240522",
    "tailwindcss": "3.4.4",
    "typescript": "5.5.2",
    "use-debounce": "^10.0.1",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/node": "20.14.8",
    "@types/react": "18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.3.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=20.12.0"
  }
}

Does anyone know what the error could be? I haven't added any packages or changed any code before the error started happening, so I don't know what could be causing it. I would share my code but I can't imagine what part of my code could be causing the error since literally nothing mentions sockets. Help?

It is probably not the answer you were looking for, but the age-old trick of turning it off and on again worked for me.
I randomly ran into the same issue. I spent a good chunk of time trying to work out what the problem was, then as a last resort, tried shutting everything down, restarting my computer and rerunning the project.
Hey, presto, the issue is gone.

as much as I hate to say but this works.
